# Do vanity lights require a junction box?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

We have an electrician at our new home in Utah installing some new lights, after removing some of the installed lights we are noticing that above the vanities there are no junction boxes behind our current light setup. The lights that are currently installed look similar to [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-3-Light-Brushed-Nickel-Wall-Fixture-6300800/203009417) - I'm curious if it is code for these to have a box installed? the lights that we are adding now look like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-3-Light-Oil-Rubbed-Bronze-Bath-Light-6748500/204708030). The electrician wants to charge us $25 a box to fix it to "get it up to code". Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: All electrical connections must be in an approved box.  You can't just have a hole in the wall that the fixture sits over.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @JPhi1618 that is exactly what I'm talking about - they just punched a hole and attached the light to the drywall

Comment: This has been addressed before. I'll look for the discussion. If the light fixture itself is an approved housing, this is fine. I've seen it done many times in jurisdictions having strict inspections.

Comment: Followup: The fixture in your first link probably has a metal tray behind, acting as a junction box and mounting bracket. The second one does not, and relies on a typical round junction box immediately behind. An old work box can easily be added, and Sparky will justifiably want to be compensated for his/her time, expense, and liability.

Comment: One final note: You'll see that I've converted some of your terminology. The confusion stems from common usage of 'gang' when describing the device capacity of a box, as in "two-gang [junction] box". A "gang box" is usually a large toolbox for a team of workers.